# Omitting the second "seemed to" in a sentence

Tags: infinitives

Someone has two dogs, one friendly and the other not so much. When you are describing the dogs, I think you can use this sentence:

> One dog seemed to like being pet, while the other **seemed to** dislike
> it.

My question is, as the phrase "seemed to" is used twice, can the second one be omitted?

> One dog seemed to like being pet, while the other dislike it.

I am not certain if the second "seemed to" can be omitted, because "the other dislike it" might sound strange ("the other" is singular, but "dislike" looks like plural).

Comment: Either *seemed to like being **petted*** (being handled, touched) or *seemed to like being **a pet*** (being a domesticated companion). And if *One dog **seemed** to like being petted*, that's Past Tense, so we would contrast that with *while the other **disliked** it.* These are much more serious errors than wondering whether to repeat "seemed to", which is an insignificant stylistic choice that makes no difference to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the past participle of "pet" is normally "petted" (at least in American English).

You can omit the second "seemed to", but doing so would change the meaning of the subordinate clause. Disliking something is not the same thing as seeming to dislike it.

Also, note that if you omit the second "seemed to", then "dislike" would become the subordinate clause's simple predicate. It would then have to be conjugated for the past tense: "disliked".